# Left- and right-aligned in a table cell

Tags: tables

I have a table, that should have l-columns. 
Is it possible to divide a table cell into a left-justified and a right-justified part?`

With other words: A left, R right: 
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l | l | l}
A Head Longer & B Head & C Head \\
{A {\raggedright  R}} & B  R & C  \\
{A  {\raggedleft   R}} & B  R & C  \\
%{A  {\flushright   R}} & B  R & C  \\ % works not
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\hspace{\fill}` -- `\hfill` for short -- is what you're looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ l | }
    A Head Longer\\ \hline
    A R         \\
    A \hfill R  \\
    \hfill A R  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{r|}{A R}  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thy. ;) .......................

Answer (score 1):

Because the justifying is done by `\hfil` primitive in each cell, you can use `\hfill` which is infinite stretchable glue with higher precedence. In your example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l | l | l}
A Head Longer & B Head & C Head \\
A\hfill R & B       R & C  \\
A\hfill R & B\hfill R & C  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx.  ............ ;)